# Convert JSON to array typescript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have some json like this

```
 const help = [
      {
        "en": [
          {
            "test2": [
              {
                "title": "Naslov1",
                "subtitle": "Podnaslov1",
                "answers": [
                  {
                    "answer": "Odgovor 11"
                  },
                  {
                    "answer": "Odgovor 12"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "test1": [
              {
                "title": "Naslov2",
                "subtitle": "Podnaslov2",
                "answers": [
                  {
                    "answer": "Odgovor 21"
                  },
                  {
                    "answer": "Odgovor 22"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I need to filter this json to some property, i have properties **en** and **test2** my new object should look like

```
const newArray =  [ {
                    "title": "Naslov1",
                    "subtitle": "Podnaslov1",
                    "answers": [
                      {
                        "answer": "Odgovor 11"
                      },
                      {
                        "answer": "Odgovor 12"
                      }
                    ]
                  }]
```

I have tried **help.en.test2** but i got error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'test2' of undefined**

Anyone can help me how to remap this, thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json). Also note that [that's not JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181).

Comment: These are all arrays, have you tried `help[0].en[0].test2[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `help[0].en[0].test2` as `help` and `en` are an array and your data is at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should try: `help[0].en[0].test2`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions on SO like this.  If you're having trouble figuring out the structure of some JSON, it helps to use the chrome developer console.  If you paste your code into the chrome dev console you can try things with `test`.

Just looking at it, `help` is an array, so `help.en` will be undefined, you need to use `help[0].en`.

Then looking at that, `en` is an array, so `help[0].en.test2` will also be undefined.  You have to do `help[0].en[0].test2`.

Of course that is also an array...